# No Launcher activity found cant find the solution

Tags: android

when i run my app on my phone it gives me this error No Launcher activity found!
 The launch will only sync the application package on the device!  I looked at some of the similiar questions but i still cant seem to figure out what the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.soloinc.meip"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity android:name="com.soloinc.meip.view.VideoRecorder"           
android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

    <activity 
        android:name="com.soloinc.meip.webpage.Webview" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />


    <intent-filter>
        <!--Viewer filter-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>

      <!-- DEFAULT LAUNCHER filter-->
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    <!--custom filter-->
    <intent-filter>

        <category android:name="com.soloinc.meip" />
    </intent-filter>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write the following specific to some Activity

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

For example in your case

```
<activity android:name="com.soloinc.meip.view.VideoRecorder"           android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

        <!--Viewer filter-->
       <intent-filter>     
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
          <!-- DEFAULT LAUNCHER filter-->
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <!--custom filter-->
        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="com.soloinc.meip" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: are you sure the activity exist on/of given palce/name?? , if your in eclipse try to add activity using gui

Comment: i have two activities one is VideoRecorder.java and the other being Preview.java

Comment: did that but seems nothing changed still same error

Comment: never mind i finally got it figured out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you only change a non-java file such as the AndroidManifest.xml you may have to force a rebuild (for example by cleaning the project - though that is overkill) in order to test a version where the change is in effect.

Comment: ohhhh, should have told about project clean(didn't crossed, i thought it was imlpied), thnks men!!